# Rails reporting objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently attempting to implement a reporting module in a rails app. Thanks to some assistance provided here: [Ruby on Rails object reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280983/ruby-on-rails-object-reporting), I have decided to go down the road of coding common metrics and populating reports with these.

What I have to work out is how to create the metrics - essentially I need to have a `metric` object that I can use within my targeting framework (e.g. if i have a `target` object where `target.value` is 0.5, I can have `target.metric_id` to know which metric is being targeted, and thus report on it).

My problem is how to store the formula for the metric within the model structure. A simple example of a metric would be profit, where I could do `sales.selling_prices.sum - sales.cost_prices.sum`. How can I set up some columns that allow this formula to be stored? All formulas will be calculated using other objects, as in the profit example.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how ambitious your formulas get, you could start with something like this for metric:

```
operation_type:string, one of %w(add sub mult div)
left_operand:decimal
right_operand:decimal
```

Then, to calculate, you might have a method on metric like:

```
def result
  if operation_type == 'add'
    left_operand + right_operand
  elsif operation_type == 'sub'
    left_operand - right_operand
  ...
end
```

When you create your metrics (maybe an admin panel of some kind) you could have ways of selecting the source inputs (for instance, left_operand is set to sales.selling_prices.sum, etc).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for - I had a vague idea like this in my head, but couldn't quite make it materialise. Thanks!

Comment: One thought - any ideas how left_operand and right_operand could be set to always use an object variable? i.e. in my metrics, the left and right operand will always be the same variable (e.g. sales.selling_prices.sum) and i'd like to be able to simply call metric.result without having to select the object each time.